# Laravel form route not defined

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-blade

I am trying to send a route the old way, without using Blade's {{}} tags. I am encountering a problem, because the framework throws my route as not defined. Can someone help me?

This is my form tag:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('companyStore') }}">
```

My route

```
Route::post('companyStore', 'CompanyController@store');
```

My controller (the function name might help you undertand)

```
public function store(Request $request){

        $company_name = $request->input('companyname');
        $company_sector = $request->input('companyname');
        $company_address = $request->input('companyaddress');
        $company_phone = $request->input('companyphone');
        $company_website = $request->input('companywebsite');
        $company_representative = Auth::user()->id;

        Company::create([
            'name' => $company_name,
            'sector' => $company_sector,
            'address' => $company_address,
            'phone' => $company_phone,
            'website' => $company_website,
            'representative_id' => $company_representative
        ]);

         $company = Company::where('representative_id', $company_representative)->first();
         User::where('id', $company_representative)->update(array('company_id' => $company->id));

         return redirect('/admin/home');
    }
```

The error is always:

```
Route [companyStore] not defined. (View:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the `route` helper, it expects a named route. So define your route as this:

```
Route::post('companyStore', 'CompanyController@store')->name('companyStore');
```

or use:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('/companyStore') }}">
```

or use:

```
<form method="POST" {{ action('CompanyController@store') }}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a route.

```
Route::post('companyStore', 'CompanyController@store')->name('companyStore');
```

and use this one:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('companyStore') }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why @nakov has propsed  `{{ url('/companyStore') }}`

Just Change

> FORM

`Route::post('companyStore', 'CompanyController@store');`

> TO

`Route::post('companyStore', 'CompanyController@store')->name('companyStore');`

Will just work